# How to find the element is dragged in jquery

Tags: jquery, drag

What are the possible ways to find the element is dragged?

I used jquery draggable() method, this conflicts with the other mouse events. Can any one help me?

Comment: Do you want to find which element is currently being dragged?

Comment: _Can any one help me?_ .. NO.. unless you show some code.

Comment: @Jude Yes I want to find which element is currently dragged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(element).draggable(function(){
 start: function (event, ui) {
    var currentDraggable = ui.draggable;
  }
});
```

or

```
 var currentDraggable = ui.helper;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic method is to use `e.target` in drag event:

```
 $('#draggable').draggable({
        drag:function(e){
           var $draggedElem = $(e.target);
        }
    });
```